Perform data manipulation using langchain
I have a pandas dataframe. I want to train a LLM using langchain to perform only specific manipulations/steps like groupby,aggregate and some other and return the modified dataframe. The code should only take the df and perform certain fixed steps and return the modified version.
I have tried a question/answering system but I don't want to enter the question each time. It should be fixed steps each time on every input.

pelase read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We'd be glad to help you solve an issue and improve the community as a result.
